# session_start() error since today

Tags: facebook, session

Since today in all my apps this error started to show:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/fb/index.php:5) in /home/fb/facebook.php on line 37
```

What changes ware made by Facebook today and how can I fix this?

Comment: How could facebook break **your** code?!

Answer (score 1):

You should remove any code above **session_start()**.
Generaly this function sould be executed before any output. *(For example HTML code)*

Another posibility it that the file encoding is not correct. 
Check for spaces and etc. before **session_start()**.

```
// whitespace, any mark up or include that displays something <HERE>
// it will give you that error
<?php
session_start();
```

Comment: It's strange that I haven't made any changes but this started today. Well I found a solution now, I changed session_start(); to @session_start(); in facebook.php and it's OK now.

Comment: That way you only suppress the warning, but not fixing it. In /home/fb/index.php on line 5 you have some output and after that you create the Facebook object. You have create the Facebook object before that output on line 5 to work correctly.